# PostgreSQL relationship conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
    public class Event
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Guid GuidId { get; set; }

        public virtual EventType Type { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Desc { get; set; }

        public Guid Author { get; set; }

        public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

        public string Place { get; set; }

        public Guid Responsible { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EventСomment> Comments { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EventWorker> Workers { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EventMember> Members { get; set; } 

        public virtual ICollection<EventInvitation> invitations { get; set; }

     public class EventInvitation
     {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Guid GuidId { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public int EventId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

        public Guid Persone { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public Guid Author { get; set; }

        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventMember
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Guid GuidId { get; set; }

        public int EventId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

        public Guid Person { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public Guid Author { get; set; }

        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    }
```

These are the 3 Entity Framework models that I use for the PostgreSQL database. As you can see here is the main Event model which has collections for EventInvitation and EventMember.

The thing is that I want to establish a 1 to 1 relationship between EventInvitation and EventMember, but all my attempts cause some key conflicts with Event and I don't know how to do it correctly.
Maybe my idea is fundamentally wrong and I am just trying to do the impossible. In any case, here's my context class to show what connections I already have:

```
    public class DataContext: DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Event> Events{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<EventInvitation> Invitations{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<EventMember> Members { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EventType> Types { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EventWorker> Worker { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EventСomment> Comments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Relation> Relations { get; set; }

        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DataContext).Assembly);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Members)
                .WithOne(c => c.Event)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.EventId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .HasMany(p => p.invitations)
                .WithOne(c => c.Event)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.EventId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Comments)
                .WithOne(c => c.Event)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.EventId);
        }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To establish a 1:1 relationship between `EventInvitation` and `EventMember`, you'll need to decide on a principal entity and a dependent entity. The dependent entity will have its primary key also serve as a foreign key to the principal entity.

For this example, let's assume `EventInvitation` is the principal entity and `EventMember` is the dependent entity. This means that for each `EventInvitation`, there can be at most one `EventMember`, and the `EventMember`'s primary key will also be a foreign key to `EventInvitation`.

Here's how to set it up:

1. Update the models:

```cs
public class EventInvitation
{
    // ... other properties ...

    public virtual EventMember Member { get; set; }
}

public class EventMember
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("EventInvitation")] // This indicates that the primary key is also a FK to EventInvitation
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ... other properties ...

    public virtual EventInvitation Invitation { get; set; }
}
```

2. Update the `OnModelCreating` method in your context:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ... other configurations ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<EventInvitation>()
        .HasOne(i => i.Member)
        .WithOne(m => m.Invitation)
        .HasForeignKey<EventMember>(m => m.Id);  // Indicates that EventMember's Id is the FK to EventInvitation

    // ... other configurations ...
}
```

By doing this:

- You're saying that each `EventInvitation` has one `EventMember`, and the `EventMember`'s primary key also serves as a foreign key to `EventInvitation`.
- You can navigate from an `EventInvitation` to its corresponding `EventMember` using the `Member` navigation property and vice versa using the `Invitation` navigation property.

Remember that with a 1:1 relationship, you need to ensure that the data adheres to this constraint. When creating an `EventMember`, its `Id` should match the `Id` of an existing `EventInvitation`.

If you decide that `EventMember` should be the principal entity, you'll reverse the configuration.